# URL Regular Expression to match exact 'n' characters before decimal

Tags: regex

I require a URL expression to match exact 'n' number of characters before decimal point. Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Can you show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below matches 2

```
\d{2}\.
```

To only match the digits put them in a a capturing group

```
(\d{2})\.
```

Or use lookaround

```
\d{2}(?=\.)
```